# convergence of any sequence in infinite space

Tags: general-topology

I consider the product,uniform and box topology in $R×R×R×R×...$. Now I believe that if it is given that any sequence must be convergent at least one of these it has to be convergent in Product topology. Am I correct?

If we can define a metric such that distance of any two terms of the sequence is bounded does it implies that the sequence is convergent in uniform topology? I need more ideas on uniform topology.

Comment: An open set in the product topology imposes restrictions only on finitely many coordinates. In box topology, it may impose restrictions on all coordinates. In uniform topology, it imposes (regarding diameter) *the same* restrictions on all coordinates.

Comment: You just have to compute $d_u(x_n, x)$, for $d_u$ the uniform metric. You cannot define your own metric, as it might define another topology.

Answer (score 0):

Define $X=\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ as the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R.$

With any topology on $X,$ we  define $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n=f\iff \{f\}=\cap_{n\in \mathbb N}Cl(\{f_m: m\geq n\}).$

The (Tychonoff) product topology on $X$ is called the topology of point-wise convergence. Because for $A\subset X$  and $f\in X$ we have $f\in \bar A $ iff there is a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}|f_n(j)-f(j)|=0$ for each $j\in \mathbb N.$ So in this topology, a sequence $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$ iff $f_n(j)$ converges to $f(j)$ for each $j\in \mathbb N.$ That is, iff $f_n\to f$ pointwise.

With respect to the uniform topology  on $X$ we have $f\in \bar A$ iff there is a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $\bar A$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{j\in \mathbb N}|f_n(j)-f(j)|=0.$ So in this topology if $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$ then $(\sup_{j\in \mathbb N}|f_n(j)-f(j)|)_n$ converges to $0,$ which  requires that $f_n\to f$ pointwise.

Closure of an arbitrary $A\subset  X$ in the box topology on $X$ cannot be defined in terms of sequences. For example if $f(j)=0$ for all $j,$ and $A=\{g\in X: \forall j\;(g(j)>0)\}$ then $f\in \bar A$ but no sequence in $A$ converges to $f .$ This does not mean that non-trivial convergent sequences don't exist. For example if $f_n(1)=f(1)+1/n$ and $f_n(j)=f(j)$ for $j>1$ then $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f.$

But if a sequence  $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$ in the box topology then $f_n(j)$ must converge to $f(j)$ for each $j,$ so $f_n\to f$ pointwise.